# TIBCO BW failing to debug successfully a REST service .I have created a jdbc resource and tested the connection was a success but i have this error

Tags: mysql, tibco

```
<>@BWEclipseAppNode> 12:12:32.545 INFO  [main] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Deployer - Started by BusinessStudio.
12:12:34.970 INFO  [main] com.tibco.bw.frwk.engine.BWEngine - TIBCO-BW-FRWK-300002: BW Engine [Main] started successfully.
12:12:35.355 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 80edabb3-8e47-001c-18c5-90bdbc610de0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Deployer - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300001: Started OSGi Framework of AppNode [BWEclipseAppNode] in AppSpace [BWEclipseAppSpace] of Domain [BWEclipseDomain]
12:12:35.483 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 80edabb3-8e47-001c-18c5-90bdbc610de0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300018: Deploying BW Application [RESTservice2.application:1.0].
12:12:40.067 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 80edabb3-8e47-001c-18c5-90bdbc610de0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300021: All Application dependencies are resolved for Application [RESTservice2.application:1.0]
12:12:41.431 INFO  [Thread-28] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300019: BW Application [RESTservice2.application:1.0] is impaired.
12:12:41.435 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 80edabb3-8e47-001c-18c5-90bdbc610de0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - Started by BusinessStudio, ignoring .enabled settings.
12:12:41.438 ERROR [CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=bw.resource.jdbc.916120c9-fbcb-45de-a13c-b22e3edf76ec)] com.tibco.bw.sharedresource.runtime.dependency.ReferenceDependency - TIBCO-BW-SR-FRWK-503000: Unable to start SharedResource [restservice2.JDBCConnectionResource] from Module [RESTservice2:1.0.0.qualifier], DeploymentUnit [RESTservice2.application:1.0]. <Reason>: TIBCO-BW-SR-JDBC-500003: The database driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] is not found.  Ensure that DataSourceFactory bundle providing this driver is available in the environment.
```

so this is the error i am getting as a result i cant run OSGi commands to request endpoint urls and for my rest service even though my code has no errors before debug ,i am getting this during debug ,please help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the MySql JDBC driver you need to install it in the BusinessWorks environment of your machine.

This is done by running the command 'bwinstall mysql-driver' from the <TIBCO_HOME>bw/6.X/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

As Emmanuel suggested, according to the error, you probably missed the required JDBC driver installation.

Once you execute the command, it will start successfully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31960140)